# Quartz trigger based on file existence?

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I am very new to using Quartz and I have a question regarding triggers. Is it possible to trigger based on file existence? I would like to have Quartz run a job until a certain file is found, then stop running that job and perhaps move on to a different one.

For example, I would like to do something like this:

(1) Job1 checks if File.txt exists in a given directory every 60 seconds.

(2) If File.txt is found, trigger Job2 to start. Job1 stops checking for file existence.

Right now, I have:

```
// Job definitions
var Job1 = JobBuilder.Create<TestEmail>().WithIdentity("job1", "group1").Build();
var Job2 = JobBuilder.Create<TestFileTrigger>().WithIdentity("job2", "group2").Build();

// Triggers
ITrigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
      .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1").StartNow()
      .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(5).RepeatForever())
      .Build();

ITrigger trigger2 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
      .WithIdentity("trigger2", "group2").StartNow()
      .Build();

// Schedule jobs
scheduler.ScheduleJob(Job1, trigger1);
if (TestFileTrigger.fileExistence == true) 
{
     scheduler.ScheduleJob(Job2, trigger2);
}
```

but it seems like Job2 never starts.

TestEmail and TestFileTrigger simply print to console at the moment. The boolean TestFileTrigger.fileExistence comes from checking if a file exists at a given location (which it does).

Edit:
TestFileTrigger.fileExistence is a boolean. Added definitions of Job1/Job2 if that helps.

Edit:
I found that if I put `Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(x));` before the if statement, the if statement will run if the condition is met. (Where x is some number of seconds.) Why does it work in this case, but not otherwise? I cannot always know how many seconds it will take for the condition to be met.

Comment: What does `getnextfiretime` say? http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/Trigger.html#getNextFireTime%28%29

Comment: I found that if I put Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(x)); after the first line, it will continue to the if loop (where x is some number of seconds). 
getnextfiretime returns the correct next firing time for the trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't understand concurrency and threading that is involved here.

The issue is as follows.

Your MAIN thread does the following.

1. Create two jobs
2. Give each job a trigger
3. Schedule Job1 to start
4. Check `TestFileTrigger.fileExistence` and if true, start Job2 (it is false so it doesn't run).

THEN a threadpool thread will start Job1. Most likely setting `TestFileTrigger.fileExistence = true`. But Main thread has already completed it work.

FIN.

At no point do you go back and check if `TestFileTrigger.fileExistence` is true. So its result is irrelevant. You are in fact checking the result BEFORE you get a result.

By adding a `Thread.Sleep` you give the job1 enough time to complete and give you a result (job1 runs asynchronously and concurrently, and it is clear you expected it to run synchronously). Imagine for example you tell your friend Fred to go to the shop to buy Pizza and place it on your desk (asynchronous), then turn around straight away and wonder why there is no pizza on your desk.

Synchronous would be if you yourself went to the shop, bought a pizza and took it home and placed it on your desk, THEN eating pizza from your desk.

`JobScheduler.ScheduleJob(job1, trigger1);` does work asynchronously.

You should create a job to wrap up step 4 and schedule that to run periodically, OR you use the built in `FileScanJob` instead.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to stop a job once the condition is met? For instance, I have: Job1 check if a file exists. If it does, sets fileExistence == true. Job2 check if fileExistence == true. If it is, does something. Is there a way to make the jobs stop once the file exists? There is `scheduler.DeleteJob`, but I'm not sure where I would put that. Inside Job1 and Job2? Inside Main? If I understand concurrency correctly, I cannot put an if loop after scheduling the jobs unless I use `Thread.Sleep`. But I do not know how long it will take until the file arrives and the stopping condition is met.

Comment: I can't help but think that `Quartz` is the wrong way to do this. You are trying to trigger on an event and not a schedule. Quartz is a scheduler, and hence adapting it for your needs is pretty hard. I personally would use a `FileSystemWatcher`.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Thank you for suggesting `FileSystemWatcher`, it seems like a much better way to do this! I will definitely try using it. On another note, would JobChaining be a potential alternative?

Answer (score 1):

What *type* of application is this?

If this is, for example, a Windows service - to keep the scheduler alive so that it hangs around to execute the jobs according to your triggers, you need to do something like:

```
ThreadStart start = SetupSchedules()
var thread = new Thread(start) { Name = "mysvc" }
thread.Start();
```

.. this would go into the `override void OnStart(string[] args)` method of the Windows service.

The `SetupSchedules` method would be the thing that hooks into Quartz jobs and would be something like (The code you've written above in the OP would make a good start):

```
ISchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
JobScheduler = factory.GetScheduler();
JobScheduler.ScheduleJob(job1, trigger1);
```

This should keep it alive so that it executes the jobs. I've omitted a bunch of stuff here, but hopefully this should give you a few pointers to help weave it into your app.

You will also need something like this:

```
private void ManageThread()
{
   var _thread = Thread.CurrentThread;
   while (!_threadMustStop) // false by default, set this to true in a 'shutdown' process
   {
       Thread.Sleep(10000);
   }
}
```

...which you call from your SetupSchedules method